# DP approach to calculate maximum length of beads

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to solve the USACO problem beads. In this problem, you are given a string of beads, and you have to find the maximum consecutive pair of red and blue beads.

Example: IF you were given the string `wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb`, the maximum length would be 11 as you would split the string at these two intervals `wrwrrbwwwbb` 
The `w` counts as both a red or blue bead, depending on what is favorable to you.

My solution is to have a count where I sort of split up each of the sections into different colors and then progressively add them and get the overall max.

Ex: IF we were using the string "rrbbwwrrb", my possible list of counts would be **[6,5]** My different sections would be *rrbbww*, *bbwwrr*, and *wwrrb*.

Logically this seems like the correct solution, but it is the coding part of it that is stumping me. Here is my code:

```
neck = "wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb"
n = len(neck)
maxi = -1 #max length
c = 0 #counter 
changes = 1 #number of color swaps
curr = 0 #each part

color = None

for i in range(n):
    if neck[i] == 'w':
        c += 1
        if changes == 2:
            curr += 1
    elif neck[i] == color:
        c += 1
        if changes == 2:
            curr += 1
    else:
        if changes == 3:
            color = neck[i]
            maxi = max(c,maxi)
            #print(str(c) + str(" ") + str(i))
            c = 1
            curr = 1
            changes = 1
        else:
            color = neck[i]
            c += 1
            if changes == 2:
                curr += 1
            changes += 1
print(maxi)
```

The correct answer is 11, but my coded solution reports 9.

Comment: Your solution appears to always start at the left end of the necklace, not trying to find the right place to break. And then it appears to try to find two consecutive runs in the part of the necklace that hasn't been inspected yet, ignoring beads that were previously included - apparently coming up with 9. So, I disagree with your assumption that your solution is correct (although you didn't offer a description of the proposed algorithm outside your code).

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea you seem to want to implement is this:

- start at any place in the necklace, keep track of what colour you start on
- keep counting beads until the colour has changed twice
- only count a change to either 'b' or 'r' as a changed, ignoring 'w'

However, your solution only starts at the start of the necklace and then goes through it once, never going back to where it was previously to check for other solutions. So, it will find a solution that's better than a random one, but it will only find the best if it happens to be in a good position in the necklace.

A fairly naive correct implementation of your approach is this:

```
beads = "wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb"
n = len(beads)
max_found = 0

for i in range(n):
    changed = False
    j = i
    current = beads[j]
    while True:
        if beads[j] not in [current, 'w']:
            if current != 'w':
                if changed:
                    break
                changed = True
            current = beads[j]
        j = (j + 1) % n
        if j == i:
            break

    found = (j - i) % n if j != i else n
    max_found = max(found, max_found)

    # this just just here to show progress, not critical to the algorithm
    if i < j:
        print(beads[i:j], found)
    else:
        print(beads[i:]+beads[:j], found)

print('Solution:', max_found)
```

Of course this goes back a bit too eagerly, checking every possible cut in the necklace, even though it could remember the length of the most recent maximum length sequence.

One way of doing that would be to remember the last position where the first colour of the previous sequence was seen and return to the position right after that, instead of starting at every single position like above. Here's that slightly more complicated solution:

```
beads = "wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb"
n = len(beads)
max_found = 0

c = 0
i = 0
while i < n:
    changed = False
    j = i
    current = beads[j]
    while True:
        if beads[j] not in [current, 'w']:
            if current != 'w':
                if changed:
                    break
                changed = True
            current = beads[j]
        if beads[j] == current and not changed:
            c = j + 1 if j >= c else n
        j = (j + 1) % n
        if j == i:
            break

    found = (j - i) % n if j != i else n
    max_found = max(found, max_found)

    # this just just here to show progress, not critical to the algorithm
    if i < j:
        print(beads[i:j], found)
    else:
        print(beads[i:]+beads[:j], found)

    # this line *is* part of the solution, but needs to happen after the prints
    i = c


print('Solution:', max_found)
```

Edit: @Krish pointed out the solution missed an edge case, the above code has been fixed, so the algorithm now also deals with `beads = "rrr"` correctly.

Comment: I would like to mention that the first solution fails when the necklace is 'rrr'.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle it a little bit differently and use recursion with backtracking. This is a brute force method, but is thorough and you know you are getting the longest possible consecutive pairings. The majority of this code is actually finding the pairs, not the recursiveness. Thanks for the puzzle!

```
def find_longest(s):
    pairs = []
    prev = ''
    for l in s:
        if l == prev:
            if len(pairs) > 1:
                pairs[len(pairs) - 2] += l
                pairs[len(pairs) - 1] += l
            elif len(pairs) == 1:
                pairs[len(pairs) - 1] += l
            else:
                pairs.append(l)
        else:
            if len(pairs) > 0:
                pairs[len(pairs) - 1] += l
                pairs.append(l)
            else:
                pairs.append(l)
        prev = l
    return max(pairs, key=len)

def solve():
    global beads
    global longest_found
    i = 0
    while i < len(beads):
        if beads[i] == 'w':
            for x in ['r', 'b']:
                beads[i] = x
                solve()
                beads[i] = 'w' #set back for next rounds
            return
        i += 1
    longest = find_longest("".join(beads))
    longest_found = longest if len(longest) > len(longest_found) else longest_found

beads = list("wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb")
longest_found = ''
solve()

print("".join(beads))
print(len(longest_found), longest_found)
```

Result:

```
wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb
11 rrrrrbbbbbb
```